# what's wrong with these?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, typed

I create a strong typed view ,but i can't get the Mode and viewdata and the Html...
This is my sample code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MiniMain.ViewModel.ArticleViewdata>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%Model %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>ViewPage1</h2>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="refereFiles" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="Breadcrumbs" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please consider renaming your question title to something descriptive and meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to add this to your `web.config` file:

```
<pages pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
       pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc"
       userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

The `pageParserFilterType` attribute in particular will enable you to use the "generic" syntax to define the class from which your pages inherit. Otherwise, you'd have to use the standard way to specify generic base classes:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`1[[MiniMain.ViewModel.ArticleViewdata]]"
```

Comment: Lck,yes!it's work !but it should be added in the web.cofig under the view path,the correct version like this: <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"> <controls> <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0,

Answer (score 1):

if model is a string, or perhaps even a primitive type, then

> 

would display it. Don't for get the equals sign.